# No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Im using py2neo(2020.1.0) to connect and make queries in Neo4j, Getting below error

`No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER`

I use `neo4j+s:` scheme to connect, When I gone through the articles `neo4j+s:` will take care of routing. But It seems not working. Is it possible to get around with this ?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? `neo4j+s` is for Neo4j starting at version 4.

Comment: 4.2-aura, enterprise

Comment: OK, that's very strange, `neo4j+s` should work in that case.
My advice would be to open a Py2Neo issue with as many details as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bolt+routing if you want to open connection to FOLLOWER, but writes to be sent to LEADER:

```
  ./cypher-shell -a bolt+routing://the_follower:7637
```